# Error while running Store Procedure from code very first run

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, recompile

I am using windows application for my project. Now in that, there is one form which has one store procedure for getting data and display on the form. Now the problem is when i run code very first time every day, it will give error. Once i manually execute that store procedure, it will working fine. So everyday very first time when i open form, it will gives error. But after that it will working fine.

Store procedure is simple and it will take only 2 sec to execute it. So i dont know what is wrong with that. I also tried various things like i have put "With Recompile" in the beginning of the query. but still it is giving error very first time.

So can any one help to come out this error and suggest me any solution to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error text?

Comment: @IvanG it gives "Object reference  not set to an instance of an object." error while run application and open form first time.

Comment: Please show that bit of code. The error message you have provided is `NullReferenceException`, it is not from stored procedure. There is something wrong in your code.

Comment: You'll need to post portion of the code where that happens.